# QString : inclass initialization of static data member of non-literal type

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Good day all

*Please note: c++ newbie*

I have taken up a project to try and discover all aspects of c++, currently I am busy creating a dynamic library. Class name `misc`

In my `misc.h`, I have several `QString`'s amoung other objects.

**Problem:**

Error:

> misc.h:17: error: in-class initialization of static data member 'QString
>
> Misc::googleDNS' of non-literal type
>
> static QString googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");
>
> ```
>                                         ^
> ```

Calling a static object from another class is done by `class::static_variable`, to my knowledge. Thus I attempt the same:

Here is a basic code example of my issue:

**//misc.h**

```
#include "misc_global.h"
#include <QString>

class MISCSHARED_EXPORT Misc
{
public:
    static QString googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");
    static QString ...
};
```

**Application Example:**

**//netm.h**

```
#include "../misc/misc.h"
//...

class NETMSHARED_EXPORT netm
{
    netm();
    ...
};
```

**//netm.cpp**

```
//...
QHostAddress ip = QHostAddress(Misc::googleDNS);
//...
```

While searching for a solution, I have attempted various combinations of `const`, `constexpr`, `static` all which, obviously have not worked.

I was not able to find a solid explaination to what is meant by non-literal,

some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I initialize the static QString member of the class?

The [best way to initialize the QString](https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html) is using `QStringLiteral`:

```
// in my.h file:
class Misc
{
public:
    static QString s_myQString;
};

// in my.cpp file:
QString Misc::s_myQString = QStringLiteral("String...");
```

This way we avoid dynamic allocation until the string content changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialise a `QString` in the header file.

in your `misc.h`

```
class MISCSHARED_EXPORT Misc
{
public:
    static QString googleDNS;
    static QString ...
};
```

in `misc.cpp` or somewhere you include `misc.h` do this

```
QString Misc::googleDNS = QString("8.8.8.8");
```

Comment: * You can't initialize the static string object member of class like in the question but yes you can initialize the instance member of class with initializer of C++ 11. QString m_str{"Whatever"};

Comment: @AlexanderVX would this suffice, since when I tested this concept above in Linux - QT creator (this is how my header file came to be), it had no issue in working, the problem came with windows

Comment: @KGCybeX You talk about initializers in the body of the class? Check on whether compiler is C++ 11 and C++ 11 is enabled in the project or `CONFIG += c++11`. And mind that is about instance members not statics.